# What Earth Science research will be done from the International Space Station?

Tags: earth-observation, reference-request, orbit

The April 9, 2020 NASA press release [NASA Astronaut Chris Cassidy, Crewmates Arrive Safely at Space Station](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-astronaut-chris-cassidy-crewmates-arrive-safely-at-space-station) mentions:

> It is the third spaceflight for Cassidy and Ivanishin and the first for Vagner, who are scheduled to return to Earth in October after a mission of more than six months during which they will conduct about 160 [science investigations](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/index.html) in fields such as, biology, **Earth science**, human research, physical sciences, and technology development. Work on the unique microgravity laboratory advances scientific knowledge and demonstrates new technologies, making research breakthroughs that will enable long-duration human and robotic exploration of the Moon and Mars.

What scientific investigations into Earth Science will these three astronauts do between now and their return to Earth in October?

Comment: If you go here https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/explorer/search.html?#q=&i=63&p=&c=Earth&g=&s= you can filter the experiments by category and expedition (this one is 63). There are 16 results, but the category mixes Earth with Space science, and I think most results are ongoing experiments rather than brand new stuff.

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival make that an answer, it's great and succinct and timeless help for future work!

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NASA [Space Station Research Explorer](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/explorer/index.html) allows to filter experiments by expedition and category. A [query](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/explorer/search.html?#q=&i=63&p=&c=Earth&g=Investigation&s=) for expedition 63 and the "Earth and space science" category yields the following 17 results (as of 27 February 2021):

- AMS-02 (Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer - 02)
- ASIM (Atmosphere-Space Interactions Monitor)
- ISS-CREAM (Cosmic Ray Energetics and Mass for the International Space Station)
- CEO (Crew Earth Observations)
- iSIM (Demonstration of integrated Standard Imager for Microsatellites)
- ECOSTRESS (ECOsystem Spaceborne Thermal Radiometer Experiment on Space Station)
- Tanpopo-2 (ExHAM-Astrobiology Japan-2)
- GEDI (Global Ecosystem Dynamics Investigation)
- HISUI (Hyper-Spectral Imager Suite)
- NICER (Neutron Star Interior Composition Explorer)
- OCO-3 (Orbiting Carbon Observatory-3)
- STP-H6-NIRAC (Space Test Program-Houston 6-Near InfraRed Airglow Camera)
- STP-H5 FPS (STP-H5-Fabry Perot Spectrometer for Methane)
- STP-H5 LIS (STP-H5-Lightning Imaging Sensor)
- SAGE III-ISS (Stratospheric Aerosol and Gas Experiment III-ISS)
- SPOC (The Spectral Ocean Color (SPOC) Satellite)
- Total & Spectral Solar Irradiance Sensor (TSIS) (Total and Spectral Solar Irradiance Sensor)

Comment: Wow, jackpot! Is "expedition 63" the mission that brought these, or the one that will execute or interact with the experiments. Sometimes it it's quite a while between something getting up there and it finally getting installed and up and running.

Comment: Yes, like I said in the comment to the question, most results are ongoing experiments rather than brand new stuff. I'm not sure how to find out which are new, sorry.

Comment: Actually if you click on the experiment name, then there is a page with some details, among which "ISS Expedition Duration" in the right panel. For example, SPOC seems to be new ("April 2020 — October 2020"). You just have to go through all seventeen! :)

Comment: Not to kill joy but those are sensors not research topics?

Comment: @Exocytosis good point, I've asked "What scientific investigations into Earth Science will these three astronauts do between now and their return to Earth in October?" and while this provides a lot of insight and sources it's not a complete answer yet.

Comment: @Exocytosis The NASA page call them "experiments" and not "investigations", I reckon. But yes, these experiments rely mostly on sensors: it's Earth science done from space, so by definition it relies on remote sensing...

Comment: @Jean-Marie Prival: so what? Remote sensing does not even make it about research. And you can use a simple CCD camera for quintillions of different research topics. A sensor is not a research topic, it is a tool and at some point you need to answer the question.